# Are there any estimates how may US citizens (or residents) have traveled to the EU after the Covid-19 "travel ban" was imposed?

Tags: united-states, european-union, covid-19, borders

*Politico* [reported](https://www.politico.eu/article/coronavirus-americans-travel-europe-loopholes/) in August that numerous loopholes apparently existed in the EU's (Covid-19) travel "ban" that supposedly kept out US citizens/residents. Among these loopholes were (fake) letters of business, travel though 3rd countries like the UK (some EU countries checked nationality while others checked only the last country of departure).

So, are there any statistics at EU level or at least in some of its (larger) member countries how many US citizens (or residents) have visited the EU after the travel restrictions were imposed, compared to say same month last year? Or any other systematic/scientific measure that would gauge the effectiveness of these restrictions, besides anecdotal evidence (to the contrary)?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50787/why-are-countries-still-introducing-covid-19-quarantines-for-travelers-from-affe. The idea that border restrictions are meaningful at this point is somewhat laughable, unless you're New Zealand, Australia or some country that is close to eliminating COVID. All these loopholes exist precisely because travel bans are purely about political grandstanding at this point.

Comment: @JonathanReez: well the EU had managed to reduce cases significantly in mid summer. Down from 30,000/day in April to around 5,000/day. But now it's [back up again](https://www.politico.eu/coronavirus-in-europe/) to April levels. I'm sure actions like Macron having declared "victory" over the virus and reopening (restaurants etc.) was the main reason for this.